# Member function called PlaySound() causes linker error when called

Tags: c++, namespaces, sdl, linker-errors, member-functions

In my class, I have a function declared called `PlaySound(std::wstring)`.  This class resides within its own namespace.  When I am attempting to call this member function from an instance of this class elsewhere, it is causing linker errors because for some reason it appears to be trying to call `PlaySoundW()` defined in `MMSystem.h`.  I thought having things in my own namespace was intended to prevent these sort of conflicts?

The linker error:

```
Error   13  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall MyNamespace::SoundProcessor::PlaySoundW(class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> >)" (?PlaySoundW@SoundProcessor@MyNamespace@@QAEXV?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall MyNamespace::Engine::Init(struct HWND__ *,long *,long *,int)" (?Init@Engine@MyNamespace@@QAEXPAUHWND__@@PAJ1H@Z)
```

The best I can understand this, is that it seems to be complaining that I'm using `PlaySoundW()` in my code, but that I've not defined it in my `SoundProcessor` class.  My function is not called `PlaySoundW()`.

I am calling my function thusly (AND from within the same namespace as the one the function is declared in):

`soundProcessor.PlaySound(TEXT("Sounds\\MySound.WAV"));`

I'm hoping this is just something obvious I've missed.

Comment: There is probably a macro of some sort, `#define PlaySound PlaySoundW ...`. And preprocessor doesn't care about namespaces.

Comment: You're right, it does say `#define PlaySound  PlaySoundW` in `MMSystem.h`.  Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: You can do as @Shaktal says. I would just rename my function though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My assumption based on the type of error you're getting and the fact that your function is in a separate namespace is that there is the following snippet somewhere (probably in a microsoft include):

```
#ifdef _UNICODE
#define PlaySound PlaySoundW
#else
#define PlaySound PlaySoundA
#endif // _UNICODE
```

These types of `#define` statements are common in microsoft's internal headers because they are designed to handle both unicode and multibyte character encodings.

In order to get around this issue, you might want to put the following before you use your code:

```
#undef PlaySound
```

Comment: Is undefining that function call likely to break anything I'm using in the Windows API?  I'm not directly calling Microsoft's version of `PlaySound()` myself.

Comment: If you `#undef PlaySound` after you include the headers and you don't call microsoft's version yourself it shouldn't break any internal code.

Comment: Right, one last thing, should I undefine this in the code where I define my function, or should I undefine it in the code where I call the member function?  Or should I do it for both?

Comment: You should undefine it where you call your member function, because it looks like it's not `#define`d where you define your function, else there wouldn't be a naming issue in the first place

Comment: Actually it would appear that undefining it in my class with the function definition does the trick.  Perhaps it does not complain about the naming because it's in a different namespace, even though these macros ignore namespaces?

Comment: My apologies, I should have gone back and read your original error; yes, undefining it in where you declare your function is what you needed to do!